# Sequence convergence with a logarithmical criteria

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have a problem with this exercise, I don't know how to start?

Let $(a_n)_{n\geq 1}$ be a real sequence, let the sequence

$$L_n=\dfrac{\ln(\frac{1}{a_n})}{\ln (n+1)}$$ with

$$M=\liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty}L_n$$
Show that if $M>1$ then $\sum a_n <\infty $ that means it converges.

Comment: Hint: this is essentially the Root Test.

Comment: $a_n$ needs to be a positive sequence.

Answer (score 0):

We need $a_n>0$ so that logarithm is defined.

There exists $n_0$ and $\epsilon >0$ such that $L_n >1+\epsilon$ for $n \geq n_0$. This gives $\log(\frac  1 {a_n}) >(1+\epsilon)log (n+1)$ or $\frac 1 {a_n} > (n+1)^{ 1+\epsilon}$. Hence $a_n <\frac 1 {(n+1)^{1+\epsilon}} \leq \frac 1 {n^{1+\epsilon}}$. To show that $ \sum \frac 1 {n^{1+\epsilon}} <\infty$ you can use the integral test.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I understood very well